# GET url in Angular/Typescript results in Unknown Error instead of success

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, api, azure-functions

I want to call a simple http function via typescript (Angular).
The http api is hosted as function in Azure.

Calling the url via Postman or directly in the browser, everything works fine.

If I call the url via http.get like:

```
this.http.get<any>(myUrl)
    .subscribe({
    next: data => {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: error => {            
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
    }});
```

I always find myself in the error part with an "Unknown Error".

But if I look into the browser's (Chrome) network tools, the request was send fine, got an 200 status and the response contains exactly what expected.

Thus, why is the error-part of the code called instead of the success part?

Comment: Have you tried .subscribe(data => console.log(data)) ?

Comment: Same. An error is printed in the console with "Http failure during parsing for https://myUrl ..."

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem myself.
The error was, that the API doesn't return JSON but plain text and I had to define the responseType explicit:

```
this.http.get<any>(myUrl, {responseType: 'text'})
   .subscribe({
      next: data => {
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: error => {            
         console.error('There was an error!', error);
      }});
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but typing `<any>` here is removing type safety that you would get by adding `{responsType: 'text'}`. Either write `<string>` or don't type out the generic explicitly (let typescript infer the type). I would go with the latter one.

Comment: That's correct :-)